# Could not identify process owning the current foreground window in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism

I'm working on browser based application automation (using Internet explorer) in Blue Prism. I have identified IE window as Win32 Application model element to be used as navigation stage to activate Internet explorer. I have installed Blue Prism in VM machine and i'm accessing VM machine via Remote Desktop Connection. Everything seems to be working fine when I'm running the process at foreground, focusing entirely into VM machine via mstsc. But when I'm minimizing Remote Desktop Connection Window means with IE at background, I'm getting error "**Could not identify process owning the current foreground window**". Any Suggestions?

Comment: Did you figured it out ? launching the login agent worked for you ?

Answer (score 1):

Remote Desktop is not supported by blueprism. You should not use any RDP connection - the most common software to peek into worker machine is tightVNC, so consider using it instead.

The problem comes form the fact that there are two users logged in onto the same machine. To fix it, restart the machine, login using process "login action" and then start the process from control room.

Comment: Little confused by statement "Remote Desktop is not supported". For clarification, Blue Prism is installed in Server and I'm running process in server itself, just accessing that server via RDP from my machine. No one else is logged in to server as no one else has access to that server. I'm running the process as proof of concept. Will there be any issue with it?

Comment: Well, BluePrism says that you shouldn't use Windows Remote Desktop or any RDP client to access the robot workers, because of issues like that. 

Again, restart machines, login using "login" process, and run the process from control room to fix the issue.

Comment: You will have different issues if you are always looking at the desktop through RDP, and then you minimise/close. You should develop to test on a FRESH, RESTARTED VDI. Depending on your working/implementation practices, you may have to 'never watch' the desktop in Production runs, if developed for an unwatched desktop. You may however, use the 'Restore button' as long as you don't minimize. Also be aware of screen resolution changes, for example if viewing from a small laptop.